# How to get and display input text from one page to another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have input field with some text in the page

http://localhost/example/package-details/?v=package1/

How can i display that value in other page?

http://localhost/example/book-now/?v=package1/

Comment: use cookies to store the value

Comment: or local storage or session storage

Comment: Please guide me little brief..

Comment: i'm cofuse about your tag? are doing it through javascript  in wordpress ? Please edit your question with what you tried so far in coding.

Answer (score 0):

a rough solution would be,, 
on firstpage.php

```
<form action="secondpage.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="textinput">
  <other inputs>
  <input type ="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

On secondpage.php, get values of input fields using $_POST['textinput'] and store it into session variable so now you can access it on any page

on secondpage.php

```
<?php
 // Start the session
 session_start();
 // Set session variables
 $_SESSION["textinput"] = $_POST['textinput'];
 //access this session variable
 echo "value of textinput is  " . $_SESSION["textinput"];
?>
```

also check out this link to know more about php [$_SESSION](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)